# A similar problem to approximation of the identity.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Somebody can to help me in the following question?

> Let $K \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $K_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{-n}K(\epsilon^{-1} x)$ and $\gamma = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\;K$. Let $f\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $1\leq p <\infty$, and $f_\epsilon = f \star K_\epsilon$ (where $\star$ is the convolution operator). Show that
>   $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} ||f_\epsilon- \gamma f ||_p =0. $$

The case $\gamma \neq 0$ is easy because I can to reduce for the case $\gamma = 1$ by considering $K(x)/\gamma$ and in such case I know a theorem that resolve this. So the really difficult case is when $\gamma = 0$.

Comment: For $\gamma = 0$ and $f \neq 0$, it's obviously wrong. Besides, even for $\gamma \neq 0$, it should be $\lVert \gamma f - f_\varepsilon\rVert \to 0$.

Comment: How are $K$ and $K_\epsilon$ related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily deduce the $\gamma = 0$ case from the generic case. Let $\varphi \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\int \varphi \,dx = \delta > 0$. Then

$$\lVert f\ast K_\varepsilon \rVert_p = \left\lVert \bigl(f \ast (K_\varepsilon + \varphi_\varepsilon) - \delta f\bigr) - (f\ast \varphi_\varepsilon - \delta f)\right\rVert_p \leqslant \lVert f\ast(K_\varepsilon + \varphi_\varepsilon) - \delta f \rVert_p + \lVert f\ast \varphi_\varepsilon - \delta f\rVert_p.$$